# Material UI - Autocomplete Styling

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield, styling

I am trying to style the padding so that the icon is pushed to the far right side in an AutoComplete Material UI component which is currently being overridden by this style:

.MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon.MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot[class*="MuiOutlinedInput-root"]

This is the code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: "blue",
    fontFamily: "Roboto Mono",
    backgroundColor: fade("#f2f2f2", 0.05),
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: '2px',
      borderColor: "blue"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: "2px",
      borderColor: "blue"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: "2px",
      borderColor: "blue"
    }
  }
}));

const textStyles = makeStyles({
  formControlRoot: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto Mono",
    width: "50vw",
    color: "#ffffff",
    borderRadius: "7px",
    position: "relative",
    "& label.Mui-focused": {
      color: "blue"
    },
  },
  inputLabelRoot: {
    color: "#ffffff",
    fontFamily: "Roboto Mono",
    "&.focused": {
      color: "#ffffff"
    }
  },
});

export default function ComboBox() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const textClasses = textStyles();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      classes={classes}
      // options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      renderInput={params => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            classes={{ root: textClasses.formControlRoot }}
            fullWidth
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <SearchIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              )
            }}
            InputLabelProps={{ classes: {root: textClasses.inputLabelRoot}}}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

You are specifying the `endAdornment` for the `Input`, but `Autocomplete` [also tries to specify the endAdornment](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.10/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L409). Your `endAdornment` is winning, but the `Autocomplete` is still trying to apply all of the CSS related to its end adornment (space for the popup icon and clear icon).

You can turn off the CSS related to the Autocomplete's end adornment by passing the props that turn off those features:

```
    <Autocomplete
      disableClearable
      forcePopupIcon={false}
```

- v4 CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-custom-endadornment-86c87?file=/src/App.js
- v5 CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-custom-endadornment-euzor?file=/src/App.js

Alternatively, if you want to keep the clear icon and/or force-popup icon (arrow-drop-down icon), you can leverage `cloneElement` to add the search icon to the existing end adornment as shown below.

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledSearchIcon = styled(SearchIcon)`
  vertical-align: middle;
`;
function addSearchIconToEndAdornment(endAdornment) {
  const children = React.Children.toArray(endAdornment.props.children);
  children.push(<StyledSearchIcon />);
  return React.cloneElement(endAdornment, {}, children);
}
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              endAdornment: addSearchIconToEndAdornment(
                params.InputProps.endAdornment
              )
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete with custom endAdornment]

Comment: Thank you! I passed in ="false" which is why that didn't work

Comment: Interesting. This problem occurred after v5 upgrade for the same code.

Comment: @Kerematam I've added a v5 code sandbox.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you very much for your time! I meant this problem in general, occurred out of nowhere when I upgrade to v5 and it is solved with your answer.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Is it possible to keep the dropdown arrow as well at the very right end?

Comment: @hotcakedev I've added an alternative solution to the end of my answer showing how to do that.

Comment: There is an easier way to add an extra adornment to a dropdown: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/17799#issuecomment-646322470 but you have NO control over the order of the adornments - the one you add always goes on the left.  So this addSearchIconToEndAdornment answer is MUCH better (because I needed the button I was adding to go on the right of the dropdown arrow).